# Lighting in C++ using a glsl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, lighting

I am currently using this glsl file to handle lighting for a 3d object that I am trying to display. I am not sure what values I need to put in for light_position_world, Ls, Ld, La, Ks, Kd, Ka, Ia and fragment_color. The scene I am trying to illuminate is centered at (427, 385, 89) roughly. I dont need it to be perfect but I need some values that will let me see my design on screen so that I can manipulate them and learn how this all works. Any additional tips or explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
#version 410

in vec3 position_eye, normal_eye;

uniform mat4 view_mat;

// fixed point light properties
vec3 light_position_world  = vec3 (427.029, 385.888, 0);
vec3 Ls = vec3 (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
vec3 Ld = vec3 (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 La = vec3 (1.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f);

// surface reflectance
vec3 Ks = vec3 (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
vec3 Kd = vec3 (1.0f, 0.8f, 0.72f);
vec3 Ka = vec3 (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
float specular_exponent = 10.0; // specular 'power'

out vec4 fragment_colour; // final colour of surface

void main () {
    // ambient intensity
    vec3 Ia = vec3 (0, 0, 0);

    // diffuse intensity
    // raise light position to eye space
    vec3 light_position_eye = light_position_world; //vec3 (view_mat * vec4 (light_position_world, 1.0));


    vec3 distance_to_light_eye = light_position_eye - position_eye;
    vec3 direction_to_light_eye = normalize (distance_to_light_eye);

    float dot_prod = dot (direction_to_light_eye, normal_eye);
    dot_prod = max (dot_prod, 0.0);
    vec3 Id = Ld * Kd * dot_prod; // final diffuse intensity

    // specular intensity
    vec3 surface_to_viewer_eye = normalize (-position_eye);

    // blinn
    vec3 half_way_eye = normalize (surface_to_viewer_eye + direction_to_light_eye);
    float dot_prod_specular = max (dot (half_way_eye, normal_eye), 0.0);
    float specular_factor = pow (dot_prod_specular, specular_exponent);

    vec3 Is = Ls * Ks * specular_factor; // final specular intensity

    // final colour
    fragment_colour = vec4 (255, 25, 25, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

1) Assuming, `light_position_world` is the position of the light in **world space**, the light is below your scene. So the scene won't be illuminated from above.

2) Assuming, `*_eye` means a coordinate in **eye space** and `*_world` is a coordinate in **world space**, you may not interchange between those spaces by simply assigning vectors. You have to use a **view matrix** and it's **inverse view matrix** to go from world to eye space and from eye space to world space respectivly.

3) The output color of the shader, `fragment_colour`, is always set to a dark red-ish color. So the compiler will just leave out all the lighting calculations. You have to use something like this: `fragment_colour  = Ia + Id * material + Is * material`, where `material` is the color of your material - e.g. gray for metal.

It seems like you don't understand the underlying basics. I suggest you read a few articles or tutorials about lighting and transformation/maths in OpenGL.

If you have consumed a fair bit of literature, experiment with your code. Try out, what different calculations do and how they influence the end product. You won't get 100% physically accurate lighting anyways, so there's nothing to go wrong.